# How are soap envelopes generated and why would .NET and php clients produce/receive different soap envelopes?

Tags: php, .net, soap, webservice-client

I am looking for information regarding what happens when a web service client created by using add service reference in visual studio 2010 makes the call to the web service and a result is returned.

How is the soap request envelope created and what determines the format?
How is the soap response envelope created and what determines the format?

This process has always been abstracted away by .net and I have never looked into how it is done, but we have a user that is using php and seems to be having an issue with the response envelope.  Below I will provide a sample of the soap envelopes for the request and the response from the .net and php code.

php request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:ns1="http://some.junk.url.xxxx.com">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:wsActionRouter>
      <ns1:i_UserId>XXXX</ns1:i_UserId>
      <ns1:i_Password>******</ns1:i_Password>
      <ns1:ActionType>CS</ns1:ActionType>
      <ns1:XmlData>
        blah blah blah
      </ns1:XmlData>
    </ns1:wsActionRouter>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

.NET request:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none" />
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <wsActionRouter xmlns="http://some.junk.url.xxxx.com">
      <i_UserId>XXXX</i_UserId>
      <i_Password>******</i_Password>
      <ActionType>CS</ActionType>
      <XmlData>
        blah blah blah
      </XmlData>
    </wsActionRouter>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

php response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <p287:wsActionRouterResponse xmlns:p287="http://some.junk.url.xxxx.com">
      <p287:wsActionRouterReturn>
        blah blah blah
      </p287:wsActionRouterReturn>
    </p287:wsActionRouterResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

.NET response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Header />
  <soapenv:Body>
    <wsActionRouterResponse xmlns="http://some.junk.url.xxxx.com">
      <wsActionRouterReturn>
        blah blah blah
      </wsActionRouterReturn>
    </wsActionRouterResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Why are the envelopes are different?

The php people are specifically complaining about the p287 namespace and are saying they cannot use the results.  I am making an assumption that they are parsing the response envelope and not taking the namespace into account.

Comment: welcome to the fun world of software standards :) (sorry if this remark offends you) but I've been in this business for quite a while and I am so fed up with things like this, I do not know if it is ignorance or bad will behind it. HTML should be standard and it is not, SOAP should be standard and it is not, SQL should be standard and it is not I do not know why do they even bother naming them standards. The only one that I found to be the most standardized so far is JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure they're using the PHP5 SoapClient and they should have no problem consuming that result.

https://www.php.net/soapclient